# Парсинг txt java

Tags: java

Есть документ

```
TITLE: Азаматтық емтихан
URL: http://www.aktobegazeti.kz/?p=97
META: "Азаматтық емтихан"|"http://www.aktobegazeti.kz/?p=97"
DATE: 03.02.2009
AUTHOR(S): N/A
TEXT: <p>
<strong>
</strong>
</p>
<p>
<strong>
Қазақстан азаматтығын қабылдаудағы кей кедергілер БАҚ бетінде әрекідік 
  айтылып жүретіні рас. 
</strong>
</p>
<p>
<strong>
РЕСЕЙ
</strong>
</p>
<p>
Ресейде азаматтыққа қабылдау рәсімі орыс тілін білу жөніндегі тестіден өтумен шектеледі.
```

1.нужно вытащить текст из заголовка (т.е. TITLE)
2.и остальной текст, без тегов и прочего( типа DATE, AUTHOR )

от тегов избавился

```
TITLE: Азаматтық емтихан
URL: http://www.aktobegazeti.kz/?p=97
META: "Азаматтық емтихан"|"http://www.aktobegazeti.kz/?p=97"
DATE: 03.02.2009
AUTHOR(S): N/A
TEXT: 
Қазақстан азаматтығын қабылдаудағы кей кедергілер БАҚ бетінде әрекідік айтылып жүретіні рас. 
РЕСЕЙ
Ресейде азаматтыққа қабылдау рәсімі орыс тілін білу жөніндегі тестіден өтумен шектеледі.
```

осталось избавиться от прочего, чтобы был текст из заголовка и оставшийся текст.

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\97.txt"));
    BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\test.txt"));
    String str;
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        str = str.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
        if (str.equals("")) continue;
        wr.write(str + "\n");
        wr.flush();
    }
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

**Обновление**

```html
str = str.replaceAll("^[A-Z].+|<[^>]*>", "");
```

добавил такую регулярку
вот, что получилось

```html
Қазақстан азаматтығын қабылдаудағы кей кедергілер БАҚ бетінде әрекідік айтылып жүретіні рас. 
РЕСЕЙ
Ресейде азаматтыққа қабылдау рәсімі орыс тілін білу жөніндегі тестіден өтумен шектеледі.
```

осталось вытащить из TITLE

Comment: Проверять, что если строка начинается с определнных слов( URL: META: и подобных), то не записывать в файл.
Такое решение подойдет?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov спасибо, попробую